# Pyspark: Standard deviation using reduce throws overflow error

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to calculate the standard deviation of a set of data without using `rdd.stdev()`. I've tried two methods and the one in which I use `rdd.reduce()` fails and throws the `OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')` error.

If I do it this way, everything seems to work:

```py
data = sc.textFile("data.csv") # Space-separated values
rdd  = data.map(lambda x: float(x.split(" ")[3])) # Only the fourth column
mean = rdd.mean() # High number: 1410000

rdd_list = rdd.collect()
part_sum = 0
for i in rdd_list:
    part = (i - mean) ** 2
    part_sum += part

variance = part_sum / rdd.count() # 5.8 trillion
std_dev  = variance ** 0.5 # 2425645. The same if I do rdd.stdev()
```

However, this way gives me an Overflow error:

```py
data = sc.textFile("data.csv") # Same file
rdd  = data.map(lambda x: float(x.split(" ")[3])) # 4th column
mean = rdd.mean() # Same mean

def partial(x, y):
    a = (x - mean) ** 2
    b = (y - mean) ** 2
    return a + b

part_sum = rdd.reduce(partial) # This throws the error: 
File "<stdin>", line 2, in partial
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

What is going on? I know using `rdd.stdev()` is useful and gives me the correct result, I'm just trying to solve it without using it as a practicing exercise, but I don't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `partial` is not correct. It would add most values more than once to the sum.

Let's assume the list of values consists of 1, 5 and 6. The mean would be `4` and the variance according to the first code block would be `4.67`  (`(9+1+4)/3`).

Using the [reduce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.reduce.html) mechanism, the following happens:

- Step 1: `partial(1, 5)` returns `9 + 1 = 10`
- Step 2: `partial(10, 6)` returns `36 + 4 = 40`

After dividing the result by the count, the variance is calculated as `13.33`. The problem occurs in step 2, when the result from step 1 is used as input for the reduce function. It is (again) compared to the mean and added to the sum. The sums become larger and larger, resulting in an error.

Instead of using reduce [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.aggregate.html) should work:

```python
rdd.aggregate(0, lambda a,b: a+(b-mean)**2, lambda a,b: a+b)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what was happening. It was being summed multiple times. I uploaded a solution in two steps using reduce. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My approach using `reduce` was wrong.
The correct method would be:

```
num      = rdd.count()
variance = rdd.map(lambda x: ((x - mean)**2)/num).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
std_dev  = variance ** 0.5
```